# Is it possible to get upload progress with Google Cloud Storage Java API?

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Google Cloud Storage for file uploads.

I've used simple code sample provided here https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/using-cloud-storage and everything works as expected.

But now I decided to improve my upload process with the progress indicator? Is it possible to receive progress with the Java API ?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @BioShock unfortunately no